# Bind the socket faster

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a BackGroundWorker that i use to listen in a port
It works pretty well, the problems is that after i sent data and disconnect, if i try to connect again the client gives me error because the application takes time to reconnect to the socket, the error is: 
 **"Connection refused by remote host"**

On the code below it takes almost 5 seconds to **listener.Bind(endPoint)**
what can i do to improve my application?

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{

    private static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program P = new Program();

        P.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        P.ipaddress = IPAddress.Any;
        P.tcpServer = new TcpServer(P.ipaddress.ToString(), 3001);

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        //worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        if (!worker.IsBusy) worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit the server.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         IPEndPoint endPoint;
        Socket tcpClient;
        Socket listener;
        int pendingConnectionQueueSize;
        IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Any;

        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 3001);

        pendingConnectionQueueSize = 100;
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(endPoint);
        listener.Listen(pendingConnectionQueueSize);

        Console.WriteLine("conn..");
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[4096];
        tcpClient = listener.Accept();
        tcpClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

       while ((rc = tcpClient.Receive(receiveBuffer)) > 0)
        {               
             string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer);    
             Console.WriteLine(msg.Trim());
        }
        listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        listener.Close();
    }
    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!worker.IsBusy) worker.RunWorkerAsync();//restart    
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you starting and then stopping the server?  Why cant you leave it running all the time?

Comment: i tried, i did a "while(true)" , but even here after i disconnect from client, it cannot connect again

Comment: you need to keep your listerner open, and not close it until you want to exit your main thread.  and you need a thread to handle each client connection.  the main thread blocks on accept - waiting for a connect. so you should loop your main thread around the accept - there are plenty of examples of this.

Comment: If the client sends a lot of data then you do get to find out that scrolling the console with WriteLine() is very slow.  Should be readily visible, make extra sure by commenting it out to see if that makes a difference.  Temporarily disabling anti-malware is next.

Comment: `Program P = new Program();` Whut?

Comment: You should have the `tcpClient = listener.Accept();` also within a while loop. I advise you looking at the [AsyncSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) which works better than a background worker thread.

Comment: If there is an exception in you code (like you said, your listener is not disposed. Use `using(var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); {  ...insert code here...... })`

Comment: Is it taking time to connect, or is it just taking time to disconnect from previous connection?  Use sniffer to find root cause of issue.